# How to use BufferingForwardingAppender along with EventLog appender to get email alerts?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, log4net

I need some idea to implement the following requirement in the web application .

I am using log4net in a custom dll to log the errors. I completed the log4net implementation and its working fine.[aspx errors are logged in EventLog and the asp errors are logged in FileAppender] .All the loggerError() methods are in the custom dll.

Now i want to monitor the logging,suppose if there is a situation like the loggerError() method is called more than 20 times in just 5 mins bse of Fatal error or database is down,then i want to track that and send email to admin.

My ideas,

1.Set a timer and count variable to  track the number of hits .

2.After each hit check the number of hits and the secs.

3.If it exceeds the threshold limit .then trigger the email...

Not sure how this will work or is there any other way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding our chat and the issue of appender being recreated every time ...  Do you have your log4net configuration (using XmlConfigurator.Configure) in your Global.asax?  Something like this:  http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2008/02/15/119657.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing your own Appender to house this logic.  The Appender could be used as a wrapper for another Appender (maybe the SmtpAppender?). The ForwardingAppender looks like a good example of a "wrapper" Appender.  As each log message comes in, apply your timing and severity logic.  If your criteria are met, forward the message to the "wrapped" Appender.

Alternatively this Appender could contain its own logic for generating and sending email (or whatever notification scheme you would like to use).

This Appender could be configured via the standard log4net configuration mechanism (app.config, separate config, etc) so the time span, error level, error count, could be configurable.

Here is an idea for how something like this *might* be implemented as an Appender:

```
public class MultiThresholdNotifyingAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
  private Queue<LoggingEvent> loggingEventQueue = new Queue<LoggingEvent>();

  private DateTime windowStart;

  public Level LevelThreshold { get; set; }
  public TimeSpan WindowLength { get; set; }
  public int HitThreshold { get; set; }

  public void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
  {
    if (loggingEvent.Level < LevelThreshold) 
    {
      if (loggingEventQueue.Count == 0) return;

      if (loggingEvent.TimeStamp - windowStart) >= WindowLength)
      {
        //Error level is less than threshold and the time window has elapsed.  Remove any queued LoggingEvents
        //until all LoggingEvents in the queue fall within the time window.
        while (loggingEventQueue.Count > 0 && loggingEventQueue.Peek().TimeStamp - windowStart >= WindowLength)
        {
          loggingEventQueue.Dequeue();
        }

        windowStart = loggingEventQueue.Peek().TimeStamp;

        return;
      }
    }

    //If we got here, then the Error level is >= the threshold.  We want to save the LoggingEvent and we MIGHT
    //want to notify the administrator if the other criteria are met (number of errors within time window).
    loggingEventQueue.Enqueue(loggingEvent);

    //If this is the first error in the queue, start the time window.
    if (loggingEventQueue.Count == 1) windowStart = loggingEvent.TimeStamp;

    //Too few messages to qualify for notification.
    if (loggingEventQueue.Count < HitThreshold - 1) return; 

    //Now we're talking!  A lot of error messages in a short period of time.    
    if (loggingEvent.TimeStamp - windowStart >= WindowLength)
    {
      //Build a notification message for the administrator by concatenating the "rendered" version of each LoggingEvent.
      string message = string.Join(Enviroment.NewLine, loggingEventQueue.Select(le => le.RenderedMessage));
      SendTheMessage(message);
    }

    //After sending the message, clear the LoggingEvents and reset the time window.
    loggingEventQueue.Clear();      
    windowStart = loggingEvent.TimeStamp;
  }

  public void Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents)
  {
    foreach (var le in loggingEvents)
    {
      Append(le);
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to configure your threshold (maybe along with your notification method) values on the appender.  Configure your loggers to send their messages to this appender, in addition to any other appenders you want to send them to (EventLog, File, etc).  As each logging message comes through, this appender can examine it in the context of the configured threshold values and send the notification as necessary.

There could very well be threading issues in this code (unless log4net handles that for you), so you might need a lock when accessing the queue.

Note that this code has not been compiled nor has it been tested.

See this link for some sample custom Appenders in the log4net repository:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/examples/net/2.0/Appenders/

Comment: What is the  namespace for LogLevel  public LogLevel LevelThreshold 
        { 
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: It it actually just "Level", not "LogLevel", and it is in the log4net.Core namespace.  I will update the sample code.

Comment: Thanks Wageoghe. I added the MultiThresholdNotifyingAppender.cs in my app_code folder and mentioned the appender name in config file.I haven't used custom appender so far. How the config section should be

Comment: I have not used log4net enough to be able to tell how to configure a custom Appender without looking it up myself.  I have added a link to one example of a custom Appender.  The link includes information about how to configure the Appender.  However, that particular Appender does not have any additional configuration parameters (like the log level, time span, etc that I described in my example).  If I were implementing this, I would configure log4net so that the custom Appender gets created but uses hardcoded values (like level=ERROR, time span=1000 milliseconds, etc) ...

Comment: That way you can get the Appender working and see if you can make it do what you want to do.  In the meantime, using your good friend Google, you can probably find some examples of how to add additional configurable properties to a custom Appender.

Comment: Rather than link to some random example, I am adding a link to a folder in the log4net source code repository.  The folder contains several custom Appenders, some that have additional configuration parameters.  There is also a sample app.config file that shows how to configure the custom Appenders.  By following the log4net sample code, you should be able to figure out how to configure the Appender that I posted above.

Comment: Thanks for the input.Yes i am developing the code you provided  and solving some errors coming up while compiling. I couldn't find the link you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I am able to configure the code to my existing project.I created a class  library and added the reference in my project.Added the settings in my web.config.But the problem is "windowStart" .How to maintain this value.  if (loggingEventQueue.Count == 1) windowStart = loggingEvent.TimeStamp; The loggingEventQueue.Count is always 1. so the time stamp is always getting reset.

Comment: As I said, the code was uncompiled and untested.  However, the way it is intended to work (and the way I would guess it would work by looking at the code) is this...  Imagine that your level threshold is ERROR, your HitThreshold (count) is 3 (so if you get at least three ERROR messages in a short time period you want to take action), and your time window is 1 second.  Say that two ERROR messages are logged in quick succession.  When the first one comes in you hit the Count == 1 statement and start the time window.  Since this is the first message and the count threshold is > 1, the code exits

Comment: When the second one comes in, it is enqueued, so Count should be 2. Since it is 2, the time window is not reset.  Since the time threshold has not elapsed, the function exits (now the queue has 2 messsages in it).  When the third one comes in, it is enqueued, so Count should be 3.  Count is not < HitThreshold, so function does not exit.  Elapsed time is within the time window length, so the queued messages are combined to be sent to the user (or wherever).  the HitThreshold - 1 check might be off by one, so the notification might happen one message too soon.

Comment: Without debugging it myself, I can't really tell if it is 100% correct or not.  There is not much code there so you should be able to debug it and figure out what is going on.  I admit that it is somewhat complicated due to the three thresholds:  log level, time span, and message count.  Set the HitThreshold to something like 5, and the WindowLength to something like 1 second.  Then test by logging 6 error messages in a row.  I would expect the "SendTheMessage" logic to only execute on the 6th (or maybe 5th due to off by one) message.

Comment: Thanks for the quik response.I am using the above logic as the dll to my project ,so it might be wrong way. Bse what i am saying is Count is always 0,the values are not maintained.

Comment: The problem is private Queue<LoggingEvent> loggingEventQueue = new Queue<LoggingEvent>(); is getting initialized everytime.So the queue is new and couunt is always 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5065/discussion-between-vani-and-wageoghe)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for a web application, I would suggest using an Application Variable to keep track of the last 10 errors.  The next time an error occurs, replace the oldest error (if necessary to keep the error count under 10) with the new error.  Put in some logic to check the dates of the error, and adjust the severity level accordingly.

Comment: I am using the dll to log the error ,so i can't store the vales in session or application variable.When the application page get the error ,from Global.asax a call is made to the DLL method to log it.Correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: You should be able to store the list of errors in an Application variable and access this list from global.asax, before the DLL method is called.  Only when there have been 10 errors recorded within a certain timespan, allow the DLL call to execute.